# How to bind data with a constant string on Windows Phone 8

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I have an `ItemsControl` in my ApplicationPage.xaml and I'm binding data to it with the following code:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Margin="24" Text="{Binding someNumber}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

When this is displayed, I want it to display a constant string next to `someNumber`. If the list contains 5, 3, 2 as someNumber values, and if the constant string is "foo" then it should look something like this:

> 5 foo
>
> 3 foo
>
> 2 foo

Is there any way I can accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use string format:

```
<TextBlock Margin="24" Text="{Binding someNumber, StringFormat={}{0} foo}" />
```

Comment: This syntax seems to give errors, however I managed to make it work with `StringFormat=foo`. At least it doesn't give errors, I'm unable to test it right now because of some other bugs. Thank you!

Comment: @halileohalilei sorry, missed `{}` in format. Now fixed, all should work as expected

Comment: You can escape the string format inner curly braces and wrap the expression in single quotes like so: <TextBlock Margin="24" Text="{Binding someNumber, StringFormat='\{0\} foo'}" />

Answer (score 0):

If the string is fixed then maybe like this

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Stackpanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Margin="24" Text="{Binding someNumber}"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="24" Text="Foo"/>
            </Stackpanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```